# JTAppleCalendar: Problems with week view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, jtapplecalendar

I'm using the [JTAppleCalendar](https://github.com/patchthecode/JTAppleCalendar) library, and I need to create a weekly view. I'm using the configuration that is suggested in the tutorials for the library, so my configuration for the weekly view looks like this.

```
ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                        endDate: endDate,
                        numberOfRows: 1,
                        generateInDates: .forFirstMonthOnly,
                        generateOutDates: .off,
                        hasStrictBoundaries: false)
```

My problem is that setting the in dates to `.forFirstMonthOnly` creates an offset and now the calendar is misaligned. I know that this is expected, however I would like to know how to disable it.

I have left and right section offsets set for the calendar, so if I set the calendar's `sectionOffset` to `UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)`, then my original insets are gone too.

Answer (score 0):

```swift
let parameters = ConfigurationParameters(startDate: startDate,
                                                 endDate: endDate,
                                                 numberOfRows: 1,
                                                 generateInDates: .forFirstMonthOnly,
                                                 generateOutDates: .off,
                                                 hasStrictBoundaries: false)
```